# Setting max-height on Reactstrap/Bootstrap CardImg does not keep aspect ratio -- how to solve?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm putting the front-end on a MERN stack app and am having trouble with Reactstrap `Card`s and `CardImg`s.  Specifically, I'd like the images not to exceed a certain max height, and also for all the content (which also includes `CardTitle`, `CardText`, etc) to stay within the `Card`

I've read various recommendations in StackOverflow, such as setting `max-height` on the image and `width:auto` but the image ends up squashed vertically -- it respects the `max-height` but doesn't adjust the width so it looks distorted.  I've spent an hour toying with different solutions and nothing works -- it seems that it should be simple but I'm not seeing it.  Any help much appreciated!

See the attached image for what I'm talking about

[image: What I'm seeing: the distortion]

EDIT: I was asked for the HTML and CSS.  The following works pretty well but the taller images are distorted when their height is limited -- the HTML (from JSX) is

```css
.project__card {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  max-width: 50vw;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.project__card .project__cardImage {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.project__card .project__cardTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:active,
.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
}

.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:hover,
.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="projectGroup__project col-12 col-md-8">
  <div class="project__card card">
    <img width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x350" alt="" class="project__cardImage card-img-top">
    <div class="project__cardBody card-body">
      <h5 class="project__cardTitle card-title">A title</h5>
      <h6 class="project__cardSubTitle card-subtitle"></h6>
      <p class="card-text">Some text</p>
      <p class="project__cardTechnologies card-text"><span>Roles:  </span>Design, Client Contact
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need a full example of your card. Please provide the rest of `html` and `css`.

Comment: Thanks, added it now...

Comment: Can you make it actual `html` and `css` rendered by your browser? You should make them into a runnable snippet. This won't run.

Comment: I've done the first part, but I think the second would be rather difficult, as I'm trying to pull out one part of one page of one route of a MERN app.  I understand if this isn't all that helpful.  I had thought there was something obvious I was missing because it seems so simple: that the image shouldn't distort when setting `max-height`, that is, the width should adjust to the height.  Perhaps it's something with Bootstrap...?

Comment: Nothing is simple enough for words and that's not even the way you're supposed to use SO. I converted your code to snippet. You should aim to ask all of your questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're setting both `height` and `width` to `auto`. The magic combination is achieved by setting one of them to `100%` and the other to `auto`, depending on which measurement you want to dictate the scale.

```css
.project__card {
  border: solid 1px grey;
  max-width: 50vw;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  padding: 3em;
}

.project__card .project__cardImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.project__card .project__cardTitle {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:active,
.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: yellow;
}

.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:hover,
.project__card .project__cardSubTitle a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="projectGroup__project col-12 col-md-8">
  <div class="project__card card">
    <img width="100%" src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x350" alt="" class="project__cardImage card-img-top">
    <div class="project__cardBody card-body">
      <h5 class="project__cardTitle card-title">A title</h5>
      <h6 class="project__cardSubTitle card-subtitle"></h6>
      <p class="card-text">Some text</p>
      <p class="project__cardTechnologies card-text"><span>Roles:  </span>Design, Client Contact
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You save me too a lot of time!

Comment: Sorry, I did it, if I was the author of this question. ;-)